# Why doesn't the Add View List Scaffolding wizard use the "DisplayName" data annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I just spent a bunch of time annotating my domain entities with Required, StringLength, Range, Display etc.

I then went in and started creating my strongly typed views that have the correct domain entity set.

The first view I tried was a List Scaffolded view for my domain entity that has Display(Name="foo") attributes generously applied.  When the view is created, the table headers still use the property name, rather than the displayname I set.

Does MVC3 with April Tools update ignore these data annotations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using [MvcScaffolding](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MvcScaffolding), then yes, these scaffolding templates ignore metadata.

But if you follow [this article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/06/mvcscaffolding-overriding-the-t4-templates/) you can create you own template. When you have done that, you can modify your own template.

Look for this part in the template

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
<#
List<ModelProperty> properties = GetModelProperties(Model.ViewDataType, true);
foreach (ModelProperty property in properties) {
if (!property.IsPrimaryKey && !property.IsForeignKey && !property.IsEnumerable) {
#>
        <th><#=  property.Name #></th>
<#
}
}
#>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

change `<th><#= property.Name #></th>` to `<th>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.First().<#=  property.Name #>)</th>` and it will use the modelmetadata displayname instead. Be cautious though that this it just to illustrate quickly how you could handle this instead, based on the template for the index view (which has an IEnumerable<> as a model).

Comment: well, am I?  :-)  using mvc scaffolding that is.  What I have is VS2010 w SP1 and have installed the "April update" for MVC.  I have not installed anything else, and am just using the wizards that appear when I choose "Add View" in the solution explorer.

Comment: I just checked. It is MvcScaffolding indeed. Check [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM13)

Comment: Yup, you are correct- installing the update does indeed mean I am using the "older" MVC Scaffolding project - it is now builtin to the MVC installer.  Thanks for your help!